# Most secure way to connect from Windows 10 to a CentOS8 Shared Desktop

Tags: security, vnc, centos8

i tried to connect to a CentOS8 desktop from a Windows 10. In CentOS8 I have enabled the Sreen Sharing feature. Then i have tried to connect to the ip address of my CentOS8 from a Windows 10 with different VNC clients (VNCviewer from RealVNC, TightVNC, TigerVNC). All of them aborted the connection with an error message like this one from TightVNC:

> Error in TightVNC Viewer: No security types supported. Server sent security types, but we do not support any of them.

Most suggestions in blog posts recommend to disable encryption at the vnc server and connect using a ssh tunnel. I also have read that somehow the vnc viewers of the world don't support tls on windows 10. But why?  What should be a reliable good to use setup for a secure vnc session?
If it comes to an alternative like rdp, i thought it is a closed protocol developed by Microsoft.

Thank you

Comment: This topic is getting more relevant these days: https://www.netscout.com/blog/asert/microsoft-remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-reflectionamplification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can disregard any Microsoft proprietary protocols by using an X11 server on your Windows box and piping the X protocols through an encrypted ssh connection (`ssh -X`).
See [this StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54089189/cygwin-x11-forwarding-using-xming), or [this link from Hofstra University](https://cs.hofstra.edu/docs/pages/guides/cygwin_x11_forwarding.html).